# ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax

Tags: ssh, sshd

I understand what each one of the alive count max do , but I can't seem to find answer for the following :

> ServerAliveCountMax  Sets the number of server alive messages (see
>   below) which may be
>            sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the server.
>            If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are
>            being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, terminating the
>            session

Let's say ServerAliveInterval is 15 and ServerAliveCountMax 10 . if the server was unresponsive for 3 serverAliveInterval (45 seconds) , then it becomes responsive . after that it becomes unresponsive again , will the serverAliveCountMax continue for the 7 remaining trials ( 15 * 7 )? or it start counting from 0 to 10 ( 15 * 10 )? in other words does this counter reset if it becomes responsive ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is "*without `ssh`(1) receiving any messages back from the server*". The man page for the two parameters `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` in `ssh_config` writes

> **`ServerAliveCountMax`**
> Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may be sent without `ssh`(1) receiving any messages back from the server. If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are being sent, `ssh` will disconnect from the server, terminating the session. [...]
>
> **`ServerAliveInterval`**
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, `ssh`(1) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server. [...]

You can see that the counters are reset as soon as *any message is received* back from the server. The message might be a response to a Keep Alive request, or it might be in-band data; that doesn't really matter to the timers.